# Using python, I am looking to plot a 3D spherical cap with a given radius r

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, geometry

I am looking to make a small program that will produce a 3D plot of a [spherical cap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap) given parameters h and a.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've started with a matplotlib example to plot a sphere...

I want to enter a value for a and h, get the corresponding radius of the sphere, then plot a spherical cap of height h and base radius a. Ideally the z axis and x y axis on the 3d plot will correspond to my initial a and h entered (as long as it makes geometric sense i presume?)

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def capRatio(r, a, h):
    '''cap to sphere ratio'''
    surface_cap = np.pi * (a**2 + h**2)
    surface_sphere = 4.0 * np.pi * r**2
    return surface_cap/surface_sphere

def findRadius(a, h):
    "find radius if you have cap base radius a and height"
    r = (a**2 + h**2) / (2*h)
    return r

#choose a and h
a = 4
h = 3
r = findRadius(a,h)
p = capRatio(r, a, h) # Ratio of sphere to be plotted, could also be a function of a.
u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, p*np.pi, 100)

x = r * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = r * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = r * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v)) 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=4, cstride=4, alpha=0.3 , cmap= cm.winter)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is your actual question? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Ah so sorry, new to the site! By following a matplotlib example I can get a sphere added in the main post, conceptually I'm not sure how to move forward from there to just plotting a cap...or if that is even the right approach

Answer (score 0):

The next part comes in limiting the range of coordinates you will accept and this could be done in a few ways. Here is one way that appears to work:

```
p = 0.8 # Ratio of sphere to be plotted, could also be a function of a.

u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, p*np.pi, p*100)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for help! I've had a go at your suggestion, some progress made but still not working fully as I'd hoped.